# How is this method of finding a maximal ideal specific to finite algebras over a field?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

Let $A$ be a finitely generated $K$-algebra over a field $K$. A typical problem is to find a maximal ideal $\frak{m}$ such that $f\notin\mathfrak{m}$ and it does not coincide (or contains) another ideal $I$.

The solution would be to use Krull's theorem that every ring with a multiplicative identity has a maximal ideal and consider the non-empty localization of quotient
$$
A'=\left(A/I\right)_{f}
$$
This ring $A'$ has a maximal ideal, which corresponds to a maximal ideal in $A$, which satisfies the required conditions.

From what I've seen, this "trick" is usually applied to finitely generated $K$-algebras over a field $K$. I would like to know if there is any reason that limits its application, i.e. can't it be applied to infinitely generated K-algebras?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean For example, if $A$ is local (which all connected finite $K$-algebras are), then $f$ is in every maximal ideal, as long as $f$ is not a unit. Could you explain further what you're goal is, and why you care?

Comment: @AlexYoucis An example of this (although with a radical ideal $I$) is described in part 2 of proof of Hilbert Nullstellensatz in http://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/00FS . I've seen several other examples of this. However, I would like to know exactly when I can use this method. I think it is relevant for the final exam in Algebraic Geometry.

Comment: Do you mean finite K algebras (finite dimensional vector space) or finitely generated K algebras? I think you mean the latter given your reference to the Nullstellensatz.

Comment: @SiddharthVenkatesh Indeed, I refer to finitely generated $K$-algebras.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maximal ideals in $B_f$ don't have to pull back to maximal ideals of $B$ when $B$ is not of finite type. (It may even happen that $B_f$ is a field and $B$ is not.)